# Cannot get fadetoggle working

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

I am trying to implement a "show/hide EXIF data" button inside Shadowbox.  Here's the code to generate the div containing the exif data, and to use fadetoggle() to show and hide it:

```
Shadowbox.init({
    onFinish: function (rawr) {
        $("#sb-body-inner").prepend("<div id='sb-exif'>This is some exif data.</div>");
        $("#sb-nav-exif").click(function () {
            $("#sb-exif").fadetoggle(250, "linear");
        });
    }
});
```

The code for the actual button is as follows (from shadowbox.js):

```
<a id="sb-nav-exif" title="EXIF Data"></a>
```

Can anyone suggest why this might not be working?  I'm very new to jQuery... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple. Because the name of the method is `fadeToggle` with camelcasing, not `fadetoggle`.

I'm guessing that if you had a look at the browser console you'd see an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fadetoggle'
```

**EDIT (in response to your comment)**

You're binding the click event after each photo is loaded and the `fadeToggle` actions get stacked. Try using the `onFinish` and `onClose` events of the shadowbox plugin, to unbind the click event when the image changes or is closed, like this:

```
Shadowbox.init({
    onFinish: function (rawr) {
        $("#sb-body-inner").prepend("<div id='sb-exif'>This is some exif data.</div>");
        $("#sb-nav-exif").click(function () {
            $("#sb-exif").fadeToggle(250, "linear");
        });
    },
    onChange: function() {
        $("#sb-nav-exif").unbind('click');
    },
    onClose: function() {
        $("#sb-nav-exif").unbind('click');
    }
});
```

You need both because content is loaded, and the `onFinish` event is called both when you open a new image and when you are navigating using the next/previous controls.

I suggest trying this alternative though, to avoid binding and unbinding the click event over and over again.

```
Shadowbox.init({
    onFinish: function (rawr) {
        $("#sb-body-inner").prepend("<div id='sb-exif'>This is some exif data.</div>");
    }
});

// this way you only bind it once
$('#sb-container').on('click', "#sb-nav-exif", function() {
    $("#sb-exif").fadeToggle(250, "linear");
});
```

Comment: Oh jeez, I knew it was going to be something pretty brain-dead.  For future reference, in Chrome, how do I access this console?

Comment: Just hit the F12 key and go to the Console tab

Comment: Yes, it did, though something odd is happening...  If you open a picture and hit this button, the first time you do it, it will fade in, and if you hit the button again, it will fade out as expected.  If you go to another picture, and hit the EXIF button again, it will fade in then out right away on every click.  If you go to a third picture, it will fade in then out then in again, and the reverse if you click it again.  Every new picture you go to, it adds on another fade in or fade out.  Why would this be happening?  You can see the site [here](http://www.element17.com.com).

Comment: Thank you so much for your continued efforts on this.  I have attempted to implement your latter suggestion, but it doesn't appear to be working.  I'm not getting any errors in the console, so I'm not quite sure what the issue is.

Comment: does replacing the `on` method with `$('#sb-nav-exif').live('click', function() { $("#sb-exif").fadeToggle(250, "linear"); });` work?

Comment: Beautifully.  May I ask what the distinction is between the two?

Comment: There is no difference as far as the end functionality goes (it's how they are implemented). I was just trying to establish if the version of jQuery you are using has support for `on` (meaning it is 1.7+). But now I noticed you wrote there were no errors in your console so I have to assume the version is 1.7+ (and using `on` should work). If that is the case, could you try `$(document).on('click', "#sb-nav-exif", function() { $("#sb-exif").fadeToggle(250, "linear"); });`? The `live` method is deprecated  as of version 1.7 so it's not good practice to use it since `on` is recommended.

Comment: You can read up on both methods here http://api.jquery.com/live/ and here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14541/discussion-between-naoh-and-spider)